# Slick carousel issue with angular 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, slick.js

Hi I'm starting with Angular 2 and trying to make slick carousel plugin to work.
This is the component using the SlickSliderComponent:

```
  @Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'banner-main',
    templateUrl: 'HomepageBannerMain.UI.html',
    styleUrls: ['HomepageBannerMain.style.css']
  })
 export class HomepageBannerMainComponent implements OnInit {
  banner: Banners[];

  constructor(private bannerService: Services) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.getBanner();
   }

   getBanner(): void {
   this.bannerService.GetImage()
    .subscribe(data => {
    this.banner = data;
    }, err=> {
    alert(err);
    })
 }
  ngAfterViewChecked() {
  $('.regular').not('.slick-initialized').slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 2000,
  fade: true,
  cssEase: 'linear'
});
}
}
```

This is html file:

```
<section class="regular slider">
  <div *ngFor="let img of banner">
    <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,{{img.image}}">
  </div>
</section>
```

Call slick library in index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Slick_Slide/slick-theme.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Slick_Slide/slick.css" type="text/css">
<script src="Slick_Slide/jquery-3.3.7.min.js"></script>
<script src="Slick_Slide/slick.min.js"></script>
<script src="Slick_Slide/slick.js"></script>
```

When i get images from local it work normal. But when i get images that encode to base64 slick did not working. How can i fix it?Please help me.

Comment: You are a bit confused, in principle you use angular not to use libraries like jquery, react, etc. This can not be fixed since it is wrong at the same time you thought it. At first glance, you do not unsubscribe with which these subcriciones will accumulate with the memory leaks. On the other hand you have to use bindings, renderer2 abstrat class implementations, animations module for  modify DOM.  Angular is not easy, learn it before writing it

Comment: @botika thanks for your feedback, i will try.